# Any guidance to built Simple and Basic trade engine?

Tags: bitcoind, altcoin, trade, cryptsy

I want to know how the trade engine works, sites likes cryptsy seems to have trade engine to automate the trade process, At first [coin-swap](https://coin-swap.net/) seems to have option for "Accept Trade", but now this also has been changed now it works similar to cryptsy, no option for Accept Trade, suppose i create a buy order in cryptsy it automatically match with sell order then i will get my buying currency

How the trade engine withdraw/deposit coins?

Answer (score 1):

The trade engine itself does not withdraw or deposit coins. It would be terrible for the exchanges, because it slows the trading down enormously, and also the fee they collect is reduced (or the fee you pay is increased).

When you want to withdraw some coins, the site checks the wallets they own who have enough balance. From one of those (Im not sure how that is selected, but there is probably some optimization there) your withdraw amount is transferred to your address. So you get bitcoin (or whatever altcoin) from a deposit wallet from someone else. This last thing does NOT mean you loose money, as cryptsy knows that you have 1 BTC (or whatever) on the site.

Anyway, the system is still the same as your [previous](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25057/how-to-accept-trade-in-cryptsy/25058#25058) question, and it is not completely clear what you are asking now. The trading works as I answered (and in the comments) over there. I hope the withdrawing is a bit more clear now.

Comment: Do you know anything about accept trade manually?

Comment: I dont know a site where it is possible. It would be terrible to trade, because when you see an offer you would like to have, the one who offered it can deny it when the price is changing. A place where it could be possible is a forum or something, where you have contact with someone and come to a deal. But I see no clear advantages from a site like cryptsy/kraken/btc-e (or whatever)?